# How to replace backslash to forward slash for entire CSV file in R?

Tags: r

I have a simple R script:

```
file1 <- read.csv2("D:/Home/file1.csv", strip.white = TRUE, header = FALSE)
file2 <- read.csv2("D:/Home/file2.csv", strip.white = TRUE, header = FALSE)

df <- merge(file1, file2, by.x = c(2), by.y = c(1)) 

df2 <- data.frame(new_col = paste('"', df$V2, '#', df$V1, '#', df$V2.y, '",', sep = ""))

write.table(df2, append = FALSE, file = outFile, sep = "#", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

File 1 is like this:

```
100;folder/path/myfile.mp3
101;folder/path/anotherfile.mp3
102;folder/path/finalfile.mp3
```

File 2 is like this:

```
folder\path\myfile;64
folder\path\anotherfile;58
folder\path\finalfile;34
```

So my script merges file 1 with file 2 based on the path column (second column in file 1 and 1st column in file 2).  It does this fine if both files have forward slashes for each row.

The problem is that file 1 has forward slashes and file 2 has backslashes so the merge isn't working.

How do I make it so that the merge will work given that they both use different slashes?  In other words, how can I convert all of file2 to use forward slashes prior to the merge?  I need the final result to use forward slashes, not backslashes.

I have looked through lots of other questions and answers and replacing backslashes to forward slashes has been asked before but only on strings.  I can't find a question asking how to replace every slash in the whole source CSV file.  So I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Many thanks.

Comment: `file2$column = gsub(pattern = "\\", replacement = "/", x = file2$column)`, replace `column` in my code with whatever the column name is

Comment: And your filepaths are just strings. Same solution as other questions you looked at, most likely.

Comment: Oh my, it's so simple, thank you!  I had to use "\\\\" (4 slashes) instead of "\\" (2 slashes) as 2 slashes produced an error and I had to use V1 and V2 instead of column names but once I changed those things it worked perfectly.  
Your answer showed me how to change the slashes on the entire file and that's exactly what I needed.  All the other answers kept referring to strings, I didn't know how to replace the entire file.  Thank you!

I can't seem to mark your answer though, I don't know if there's a minimum time or something before I can mark.

Comment: Your column names are `V1` and `V2`. Once you read it in to R, it's not a file anymore. It's just a data frame with text in it. Text data are often called "strings".

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it is very useful to me.  But can you tell me why I can't mark your answer?  Is it because it's a comment?  I'd like to mark this as answered so you get the credit.

Comment: Yes, I just posted it as an answer so it's acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
file2$column = gsub(pattern = "\\\\", replacement = "/", x = file2$column)
```

Replace `column` in my code with whatever the column name is.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.  It replaces every backslash in the file exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Another regex could be the following.

```
x <- 'a\\b\\c'
gsub('[\\]', '/', x)
#[1] "a/b/c"
```

Or, using argument `fixed = TRUE`,

```
gsub('\\', '/', x, fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "a/b/c"
```

Now it's a matter of applying the above to the column(s) of the dataframe.